# Log info is not printing on console

Tags: java, logging

In my Struts project I am using Loggers. I am running my WSAD server in Debug Mode. Here the below condition is satisfying but it is not printing the log info in console.

```
if(count.intValue() > 1)
{
    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
        log.info("many");

    return mapping.findForward("many");
}
```

Here I set my Logger level to INFO.

Comment: Is confusing the reader by using counterintuitive indentation intended?

Comment: how it is counterintuitive.In Second if condition is also satified. But the log.info is not printing on console.

Comment: Maybe because the logging level is set to `INFO`, so that `isDebugEnabled` returns `false`?

Comment: yes. it might be. i will check.

Comment: @Jesper: if DEBUG is enabled then INFO is enabled implicitly. You cannot selectively enable one level without enabling everything higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I wasn't suggesting anything that has to do with selectively disabling one level. Look closely at the code: he checks for the `DEBUG` level with `isDebugEnabled` but then logs at the `INFO` level inside the `if`. So, if the level is set to `INFO`, he is **not** going to see anything logged, because if the level is `INFO` then `isDebugEnabled` will return `false`, skipping his `log.info` statement.

Comment: The counter-intuitive indentation that Tomasz was referring to is that the return statement is indented from the nested if, but is not actually the statement being controlled by the if statement.

Comment: @Jesper: I am sorry, you are right. If debug is disabled, info can still be enabled. This can actually be the case here.

Comment: @Jesper Post your first comment as an answer.  I caught the same thing and it sounds like that is the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A "lower" logging level includes all the "higher" levels:

```
ERROR > WARN > INFO > DEBUG
highest ------------ lowest
```

That means for example that when you set the level to DEBUG, you'll also get INFO, WARN and ERROR messages; if you set it to INFO, you'll see ERROR, WARN and INFO but not DEBUG messages, etc.

Look at these lines:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    log.info("many");
```

What is confusing here is that you test if the DEBUG level is active (with `isDebugEnabled`), but you actually log at the INFO level.

So, what happens here if the level is set to:

- DEBUG: You'll see the message, because DEBUG includes INFO messages.
- INFO: You will **not** see the message, because `isDebugEnabled` returns `false` when the level is set to anything higher than DEBUG. That means the statement inside the `if` is not executed and you don't see the message.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesper said, `isDebugEnabled` will only return true when the log level is at least set to `DEBUG`, so remove that check or set the log level to `DEBUG`. The `DEBUG` level includes `INFO`, but `INFO` doesn't include `DEBUG`.